# How to change wrapper class initialization in Java 9?

Tags: java, boolean, deprecated, java-9

As everyone knows from java 9, the most of the constructors of wrapper classes are deprecated.

As eg :

```
new Boolean(true): Deprecated : Instead use Boolean.valueOf(true);
new Boolean("false") : Deprecated : Instead use Boolean.parseBoolean("false");
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html

Just wanted to know, if there is any tool or api designed/created to do this changes, or we need to create our own script/program/ manual changes to do so?

Just thought of writing a shell script which will read all files in directory and replace new Boolean with the valueOf.
But I got stuck, because in file reading , I will never know what will be the argument type? boolean or String ,and when to use valueOf and parseString in above example.

Comment: Use IDE's RegEXP search and replace utility

Comment: I can use that, but that again won't be able to tell that valueOf should be use or parseBoolean should be used.

Comment: It is almost never necessary to call Boolean.valueOf(boolean).  Autoboxing does that for you.

Comment: @VGR I was talking about Boolean.parseBoolean("true"). The parameter is string here.

Comment: If you’re not on a Windows system, or if you’re on Windows and have Cygwin installed, you may be able to use `find /path/to/project -name '*.java' -exec sed -i 's/new Boolean\(([^)]*)\)/Boolean.valueOf\1/g' '{}' +` to lighten the load.  I don’t think it’s possible to use a regular expression to match arbitrary levels of nested parentheses, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use of any good editor can help you here. You ideally just need a good find and replace approach to be able to differentiate `new Boolean("false")`  versus `new Boolean(false)`.

For example, using intelliJ one can clearly see the different strings matched while finding `new Boolean(true)` when at the same time the code block includes `new Boolean("true")` as well.

[image]

***PS***: A similar approach would work with find and replace all while performing the same on the root directory of the project as well. Here is the [guide from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html) about the same.

Comment: That's ok with editor. But suppose I have around 500+ classes, which has such wrapper object initialization. I don't want to do that manully by opening each and every class in editor.

Comment: @ArnabDhar There is a ReplaceAll and FindAll(given a directory path) option available with IDEs as well for that purpose itself